# Do you need to call shmat and shmget in both producer and consumer files?

Tags: c, shared-memory, producer-consumer

In the producer process, I have the following.
say

- MEMKEY is key_t 234500, and
- *shared_ring is a pointer to the data structure (donut_ring) that is being shared.

  `int shmid, semid[3];`

  ```
      if((shmid = shmget (MEMKEY, sizeof(struct donut_ring),
                  IPC_CREAT | 0600)) == -1){
  perror("shared get failed: ");
  exit(1);
  ```

  }

  ```
  if((shared_ring = shmat (shmid, NULL, 0)) == (void *)-1){
  perror("shared attach failed: ");
  sig_handler(-1);
  ```

  }

The consumer and producer programs are suppose to be in separate files.

How can each consumer find the **shared memory id** created by the producer, and attach the segment to their address space?

Do I need to call the shmat shmid again in the consumer file, and for each consumer process that is forked? wouldn't it create a new one instead of using the one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the answer is Yes. Both calls are necessary in both files.